# Cuda: data corruption in memory after kernel call

Tags: memory, cuda

Please look this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int N, L, I;
float * inputs;
float * temp;

// first kernel
__global__ void mulKernel ( float * output, float * inputs)///, float * weights)
{
   int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

   output [idx] = inputs [idx] * 3;//weights [idx];
   //weights [idx] = 4;

   //__syncthreads();
}

//second kernel
__global__ void sumKernel ( float * output, float * input)
{
   int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   output [idx] = input[idx]*2;

   __syncthreads();
}

void printVector (const float *p, const int N) {
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    printf("%f\n",p[i]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 3)
        printf("Usage: cuda <layers> <inputs>\n");
    else
    {
        L = atoi(argv[1]);
        N = atoi(argv[2]);
        I = atoi(argv[2]);
        inputs = (float*)malloc(I*sizeof(float));
        float * weights = (float*)malloc(I*sizeof(float));

        // and fill with some arbitrary values
        for (int i=0; i<I; i++)
        {
            inputs[i] = 1;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<I; i++)
        {
            weights[i] = 1.5;
        }

        // allocate device memory
        float * devInputs = NULL;
        float * devTemp = NULL;
        float * devWeights = NULL;

        cudaMalloc ( (void**)&devInputs, I*sizeof(float) );
        cudaMalloc ( (void**)&devTemp, I*sizeof(float) );
        cudaMalloc ( (void**)&devWeights, I*sizeof(float) );

        // set kernel launch configuration
        dim3 threadsMul = dim3(512, 1);
        int blocksCount = floor(I / threadsMul.x) + 1;
        dim3 blocksMul  = dim3(blocksCount, 1);

        dim3 threadsSum = dim3(512, 1);
        blocksCount = floor(I / threadsSum.x) + 1;
        dim3 blocksSum  = dim3(blocksCount, 1);

        cudaMemcpy      ( devInputs, inputs, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
        cudaMemcpy      ( devWeights, weights,I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

        //kernels calling in this cycle
        for(int j=0;j<L;j++)
        {
            // copying data to see that's ok
          cudaMemcpy      ( inputs, devInputs, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
          cudaMemcpy      ( weights, devWeights, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

            // print it
          printf("inputs:\n");
          printVector (inputs, N);
          printf("weights:\n");
          printVector (weights, N);
          printf("\n");

            // running first kernel
          mulKernel<<<blocksMul, threadsMul>>>(devTemp, devInputs);//, devWeights);

            // copying and printing data. We can see thats array weights contains a wrong values
          cudaMemcpy      ( inputs, devInputs, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
          cudaMemcpy      ( weights, devWeights, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

          printf("inputs:\n");
          printVector (inputs, N);
          printf("weights:\n");
          printVector (weights, N);
          printf("\n");

          if(cudaDeviceSynchronize() == cudaSuccess)
            printf("threads syncronized\n");

          cudaMemcpy      ( inputs, devInputs, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
          cudaMemcpy      ( weights, devWeights, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

          printf("inputs:\n");
          printVector (inputs, N);
          printf("weights:\n");
          printVector (weights, N);
          printf("\n");

          sumKernel<<<blocksSum, threadsSum>>>(devInputs, devTemp);

          cudaMemcpy      ( inputs, devInputs, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
          cudaMemcpy      ( weights, devWeights, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

          printf("inputs:\n");
          printVector (inputs, N);
          printf("weights:\n");
          printVector (weights, N);
          printf("\n\n");

          if(cudaDeviceSynchronize() == cudaSuccess)
            printf("threads syncronized\n");

          cudaMemcpy      ( inputs, devInputs, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
          cudaMemcpy      ( weights, devWeights, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

          printf("inputs:\n");
          printVector (inputs, N);
          printf("weights:\n");
          printVector (weights, N);
          printf("\n\n");
        }

        cudaMemcpy      ( inputs, devInputs, I*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

        cudaFree         ( devInputs   );
        cudaFree         ( devTemp   );
        cudaFree         ( devWeights   );

        printVector (inputs, N);

        free(inputs);
        free(weights);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And look the output. After callig first kernel, the devWeights array lost its data. But it doesn't used anywhere. I just copy it to the memory, run kernels (that don't affects it) and copy back to host. And in output I see that it changed. Why? What am I doing wrong?

In main function you can see cycle for. In it I run two kernels: sumKernel and mulKernel. Before running kernel, after it, and after synchronization threads I copy arrays to host and print it. So, I see wrong data after calling kernel. See comments in code.

I don't see any error (only cudaSuccess).

Comment: You do not check for CUDA errors at all.  If you don't check for errors, you will never know if anything went wrong.

Comment: Without kernel call code we can just guess. How did it changed? You sure you called your kernel with correct arguments in correct order?

Comment: You ask us to "Look at the output". But you have not explained anything about what it should look like or what the code does (or what values of the command line arguments you use when the problem happens). How is someone else supposed to know what *your* code is supposed to do and help identify the problem if you don't make the effort to explain it to them or tell them how you are supposed to run the code to produce the problem?

Comment: I edited post. See comments in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found the error. I forgot to use if(idx < N) in my kernels and CUDA didn't print error when gone out array dimensions. So, when I changed inputs array, I also changed data that situated in memory after inputs.